# Given $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and function $Z=f(r)$ prove that the function fulfills $yZ_x=xZ_y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> Given $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and function $Z=f(r)$ prove that the function fulfills $yZ_x=xZ_y$, $Z(x,y)$. We can suppose that we can use chain rule. Also a hint is given that essentially we need to prove that any function which is only dependent on the distance from the origin fulfills $yZ_x=xZ_y$.

I don't quite understand this problem.

1) Is $Z=f(r)$ a single variable function now?

2) Is there any connection between the $r$ from $f(r)$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$? Can $r$ be anything? Can it be a complicated expression of any form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see $f(r)$ as some function of $r^2$ (consider $f(r)=f(\sqrt{r^2}$))

$g(r^2)=f(r)=Z$ and let be $w=r^2=x^2+y^2$

$Z_x=\dfrac{dg}{dw}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial x}=g'2x$

$Z_y=\dfrac{dg}{dw}\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial y}=g'2y$

$yZ_x=yg'2x=xg'2y=xZ_y$

Comment: While we can prove the required when we define $f(r)=g(r^2)$ what if $f(r)=g(r^3)$ or etc? It just looks to me like a proof of a specific case

Comment: No, no, it works well with $r^3$ or whatever. Try to prove it differentiating $g(e^r)$, you'll see it's true too. I simply applied a variable change to differentiate with ease, as with any other differential equation.

Comment: I understand that it'll work with $r^n$ and other functions dependent only on $r$ but from your substitution doesn't it follow that $r^2=r \Rightarrow r=1$?

Comment: No, it's true that $r=\sqrt{r^2}$, only this. What I did is this: $f(r)=f(\sqrt{r^2})$, but now we have a some other function of $r^2$, so is $g$ You'll get it with an example. $f(r)=e^{r^2}$, it's obviously a function of $r$, this function: $f(x)=e^{x^2}$. But you can see it as function of $r^2$, this function: $g(x)=e^x$. I insist, use e.g. $g(e^r)$ (or $h(r^3)$) and calculate $Z_x$ and $Z_y$ you'll see it works the same.

Comment: I posted a follow up question on this one, if you're interested https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286553/how-to-prove-that-if-z-zr-cos-theta-r-sin-theta-fr-theta-then-f-thet

Answer (score 2):

Think of $f$ as any function of one variable differentiable at $(0,+\infty)$. Then $Z(x,y) = f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and as you can see, $Z$ is function of two variables and is given as a composition of $f$ and function $(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now use chain rule:

$$Z_x(x,y)=f'\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\frac \partial{\partial x}\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$
$$Z_y(x,y)=f'\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\frac \partial{\partial y}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes. Should I also show $f'(-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$?

Comment: @Yos, your hint treats $r$ as distance from origin, which is nonnegative. But, technically, you are right. I'd advise you to go with approach given in the answer by Rafa, I just wanted to give you sense of what is going on.

Comment: I like your approach more because we prove everything on $f(r)$ "as is". While in Rafa's approach I don't like that we choose $f(r)$ to be equal to something specific