# How to prove that if $Z=Z(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)=F(r,\theta)$ then $F_{\theta}=0$ when $yZ_x=xZ_y$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> How to prove that if $Z=Z(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)=F(r,\theta)$ then $F_{\theta}=0$ when $yZ_x=xZ_y$?

I tried diffentiating $F_{\theta}$:
$$
F_{\theta}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot-r\sin\theta+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot r\cos\theta
$$

How to I arrive to $F_{\theta}=0$?

Comment: You have it almost done:  What are $x$ and $y$ in polars? The derivatives "cross" the sine and the cosine. Rewrite the hypotesis.

Comment: @RafaBudría what do you mean by "cross"? I guess because $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ this equation is just another form of $Z=f(r)$ from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286401/given-r2-x2y2-and-function-z-fr-prove-that-the-function-fulfills-yz-x#2286432                         By the way the fact that $F_{\theta}=0$, does this tell us anything?

Comment: Sine goes to cosine and viceversa. And yes, it is, but the proposition to prove is the converse one.

Comment: @RafaBudría but what follows from the fact that $F_{\theta}=0$? Is the function flat or something?

Comment: $F_\theta$ can be seen as the variation of $F$ along a direction always perpendicular to the position vector of the point at where we are evaluating $F$ (and having as modulus our $r$). This variation must be zero as the function only depends on $r$. Another way to see it is as $F$ being symmetric for rotations: you calculate $F$ for some values of $x_0$ and $y_0$, then, rotate the axes in an amount of $\theta$ and the value of $F$ for the same values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ it's the same too. The condition you asked to prove is a nice form to express this symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write
$$F_{\theta}=\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\theta} = \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}$$
$$=Z_x\cdot(-r\sin\theta)+Z_y\cdot(r\cos\theta)$$
$$=-yZ_x+xZ_y$$
which is zero by hypothesis.